# PHPunit Dispatch controller action with POST and form

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I have a PHPunit test like this:

```
    public function testUsersCanRegisterWhenUsingValidData()
  {

    $this->request->setMethod('POST')
         ->setPost(array(
             'username'         => 'user123',
             'zip_code'         => '43215',
             'email'            => 'me1@something.com',
             'password'         => 'secret',
             'confirm_pswd'     => 'secret',
           ));

    $this->dispatch('/account/register');

    $this->assertRedirectTo('/account/login');

  }
```

and a User controller action called register like this :

```
       public function registerAction()
        {

          // Instantiate the registration form model
          $form = new Application_Model_FormRegister();

          // Has the form been submitted?
          if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

            // If the form data is valid, process it
            if ($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost())) {

              // Does an account associated with this username already exist?
              $account = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Account')
                              ->findOneByUsernameOrEmail($form->getValue('username'), $form->getValue('email'));          

              if (! $account)
              { // do something
    .............
    ..............

} else {

            $this->view->errors = array(
              array("The desired username {$form->getValue('username')} has already been taken, or
              the provided e-mail address is already associated with a registered user.")
            );

          }

        } else {
          $this->view->errors = $form->getErrors();
        }

      }

      $this->view->form = $form;

    }
```

I get an error in this line :

```
$account = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Account')
                                  ->findOneByUsernameOrEmail($form->getValue('username'), $form->getValue('email'));
```

It's caused by $form->getValue('username') being NULL because the form has not actually been submitted, instead PHPunit has dispatched the action and set up the POST variables.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry everyone. I had commented out this line to try and study my problem:

```
// If the form data is valid, process it
        if ($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost())) {
```

and it turns out that my input test input was not valid and you can't use $form->getValue to get the value of an invalid form.

I didn't get any answers because this line was not commented out in my post and would have worked. Slap head............MODS feel free to delete this post if you think it is no help to anybody.